# How to restore Unix permissions?

Tags: permissions, ntfs, ext4

I copied all of my files in /home directory (ext4 partition) to an NTFS drive partition. But when I copied them back to my /home directory, all the Unix permissions were gone and I could not open my programs, such as Qt. So how to restore the initial Unix permissions for all the files?

Comment: Short answer: unless you saved the permissions, you can't.

Comment: :( :( :( :( :( :(

Comment: Since the files in question are under `/home` it is possible that `chmod 700 -R /home` or `chmod 755 -R /home` will solve your problem (using a default permission which might be good enough for you)